# WPF : How to prevent child controls to be rotate in canvas

Tags: wpf

[image]

In attached image labels with marked "not ok" are rotating within canvas.  I want to prevent that behaviour.

Please help me.

Comment: one must have added rotation functionality

Comment: one must be trolled for not providing code sample

Answer (score 0):

As the labels are child objects they will rotate with the parent object - that's what they are designed to do.

You will have to apply the **inverse** of the parent rotation to the labels - making sure that you keep the positional offset correct. This would be done the simplest by having a second property to hold the inverse and binding that to the rotation transform of the labels.

So each TextBlock would need the following:

```
<TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="{Binding InverseParentAngle}"/>
</TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
```

The centre properties ensure that the rotation is around the centre of the label and the `InverseParentAngle` is the negative of the canvas rotation.

You could bind the angle to the angle of the canvas through a converter that negated the value, rather than having to maintain a second property. That might be a cleaner approach.

```
<TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="{Binding (Canvas.Angle),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Converter={StaticResource=InverseConverter}"/>
</TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but it would be a great help if you can share this type example.